# Trying to get property of non-object?

Tags: php, html, dom, domdocument

I've been getting an error message for the following piece of code (I'm trying to get the content inside the 'article' tags on a certain web page):

```
function getTextFromLink($url) {
    $html = new DOMDocument();
    $html->loadHTML($url);
    $text = $html->getElementsByTagName('article')->item(0)->textContent;
    return $text;
}
```

It says that I'm trying to get the property of a non-object on the line with

```
$text = $html->getElementsbyTagName('article')->item(0)->textContent;
```

I'm fairly new to php and DOM; what am I missing here?

Comment: Run `var_dump($html->getElementsbyTagName('article')->item(0));` and you'll see that it isn't an object.   Might give you a clue on breaking it down, you can continue to break it down further from there.

Comment: @JackSmith: That's slightly different -- the problem in your linked question is that the value is not an object but an array, while the problem *here* is that the value is *null*. Both are, of course, not objects, but I doubt the answers to that question would be particularly useful to the OP.

Answer (score 4):

You have two problems in your code:

The *obvious* problem is that `$html->getElementsByTagName('article')->item(0)` is not an object.  Specifically, it is null, since the HTML you're parsing doesn't actually contain any `article` elements.  You could've figured this out yourself by following [Devon's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34279306/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object#comment56300695_34279306) and viewing the value of `$html->getElementsByTagName('article')->item(0)` using `var_dump()`.

Now, *why* doesn't your HTML contain any `article` elements?  Well, the *real* problem turns out to be that the [`loadHTML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) method will load HTML *from a string* and parse it.  That is to say, when you call `$html->loadHTML($url);`, PHP will parse the contents of the string variable `$url` as HTML code, and give you a DOMDocument representing the result.  Given that you named the variable `$url`, I'm pretty sure that's *not* what you want.

What you actually want to use instead is probably [`loadHTMLFile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php), which actually loads HTML code from a named file (or, apparently, URL), rather than from a PHP string.